# Powershell single quote vs double quote

Tags: performance, powershell

I know that difference between using single quote instead of double quote is that variables aren't expanded.

```
$a = "hello"
"$a world"    # hello world
'$a world'    # $a world
```

I am accustomed to use double quote, but I guess that single quote could be more efficient. Is this always true? Is there some documentation about this topic? I googled a bit but results are overwhelmed by explanation about expanding variables

Answer (score 6):

Efficiency is very probably a non-issue if you don't have embedded variables or subexpressions.

A quick test with `Measure-Command` showed no difference at all.

Answer (score 5):

My preference is to use single quotes for anything that doesn't require expansion.

Comment: That's my habit as well ... it only hurts when I start doing that in C# too ;-)